# UBUNTU for Windows 8.1?

Tags: 12.04, windows, files, system-installation, microsoft-office

I would like to install your OS into my laptop (gaming x64bits ) that currently uses Windows 8.1 Pro And I would like to know if this will remove Windows or have both OS and if this will keep any of my files/programs Windows Office,Games and Docs/Images

Thank You for your time.

Comment: Please see the following for a walk-through on how to install Ubuntu. http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Always best to have full backup of your current system, if making major changes. Even new drives fail, so you should have some backup procedure in place. You will have UEFI install https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI And: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 0):

Just put the disk in and install it . In the install dialog it will ask if you want to keep windows,  choose yes and Ubuntu will be installed alongside Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu asking as your Boot Manager....I've done this a few times and it always works...Ubuntu is awesome at working with Windows (7 and 8 and 8.1 I know for sure)